# how to see view state size for non system administrator profiles?

Tags: performance, viewstate

I am working on a product in which multiple profiles are applicable for same features (*Data is coming according to profile and there are also some layout changes*). I like to see the view state of page for each profile. According to my knowledge I have to enable "**Development Mode**" and "**Show View State in Development Mode**" setting.

I am not able to find this setting for **Non System Administrator** profiles. 
So I like to know that there are possibility to view view state for **Non System Administrator** Profile.